# How to start at a specific letter and end when it hits a digit?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have some sample strings:

```
s = 'neg(able-23, never-21) s2-1/3'
i = 'amod(Market-8, magical-5) s1'
```

I've got the problem where I can figure out if the string has `'s1'` or `'s3'` using:

```
word = re.search(r's\d$', s)
```

But if I want to know if the contains `'s2-1/3'` in it, it won't work.
Is there a regex expression that can be used so that it works for both cases of 's#' and 's#+?
Thanks!

Comment: You want to capture `"s2-1/3"`, on what basis exactly? Are characters other than digits, `"-"`, and `"/"` allowed?

Comment: I would like to know both ways, if possible. 1 case where it returns a match where it contains ONLY `"-"` and "/" along with an s, and another case where it has `"s"` followed by anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow the characters `"-"` and `"/"` to be captured as well, in addition to just digits. It's hard to tell the exact pattern you're going for here, but something like this would capture `"s2-1/3"` from your example:

```py
import re

s = "neg(able-23, never-21) s2-1/3"

word = re.search(r"s\d[-/\d]*$", s)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped. I wanted it to be able to find it in both cases though. I combined your statement along with mine using an if statement which works `if (re.search(r"s\d+[-/\d]+$", l.rstrip()) or re.search(r's\d$', l.rstrip()))`, but is there a way to do it in 1 statement?

Comment: @EddieZeng Oh so like `"s1"` or `"s1-2/3"` would match for example?

Comment: Yep, Sorry if I wasn't clear but I don't want to return `s1` or `s2-1/3`, I just want to know if they match. This is part of a program that I am currently writing where I need to filter lines that contain these markings.

Comment: Yes it does, thanks. If you edit your answer I can approve it

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that maybe you would want to extract that with some expression, such as:

```
(s\d+)-?(.*)$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/w9AJqn/1/)

or:

```
(s\d+)-?([0-9]+)?\/?([0-9]+)?$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/OdD1ac/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

expression = r"(s\d+)-?(.*)$"
string = """
neg(able-23, never-21) s211-12/31
neg(able-23, never-21) s2-1/3
amod(Market-8, magical-5) s1
"""
print(re.findall(expression, string, re.M))
```

#### Output

```
[('s211', '12/31'), ('s2', '1/3'), ('s1', '')]
```